# Run the python script in Remote Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, rpa

Python>Sample.py | ssh user@172.28.40.12 python -
while im run the above cmd in cmd prompt
ssh: connect to host 172.28.40.12 port 22: Connection refused

can u give the explain while i get the error or how to run the python script in remote desktop from the local machine

Comment: That would run the script in your computer and pipe the output to the remote machine.

Comment: Don't you want `ssh user@172.28.40.12 "python Sample.py"`?

Comment: Also `cat Sample.py | ssh user@172.28.40.12 python` or something similar, I'm not sure if the interpreter would execute the code like this or needs some kind of flag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.